# generate_messages fails with ros_comm

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-comm, generate-messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While installing with source, I've started seeing this error after synching `ros_comm` src to the [latest](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/commit/c45a8c57d9b445abdf4f1cd48adb68fd16720311) commit (not sure if the error starts happening since this particular commit or earlier).

So far I only see this error while building either/both [rqt_common_plugins](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/tree/52853196be6c53c6fdc58e28f2150adc7d281f4a) or/and [rqt_robot_plugins](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_robot_plugins/tree/0b9b2c8ef4e1af6062607a349cb7f5614296d496) metapkgs, particularly with the packages `rqt_image_view`, `raqt_rviz` where neither of them use the `target` mentioned in the error message.

The error doesn't happen when I switch `ros_comm` to binary (`1.9.46-0quantal-20130625-1625-+0000`).

catkin 0.5.67, Ubuntu 12.10

````
$ catkin_make
:
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'roscpp'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros_comm/clients/roscpp)
-- Boost version: 1.49.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   signals
--   filesystem
--   system
-- roscpp: 1 messages, 3 services
CMake Error at /home/rosuser/catkin_ws/build/ros_comm/clients/roscpp/cmake/roscpp-genmsg.cmake:53 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "roscpp_generate_messages_cpp"
  because another target with the same name already exists.  The existing
  target is a custom target created in source directory
  "/home/rosuser/catkin_ws/src/rqt_common_plugins/rqt_image_view".
  See documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/groovy/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:280 (include)
  ros_comm/clients/roscpp/CMakeLists.txt:35 (generate_messages)


CMake Error at /home/rosuser/catkin_ws/build/ros_comm/clients/roscpp/cmake/roscpp-genmsg.cmake:100 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "roscpp_generate_messages_lisp"
  because another target with the same name already exists.  The existing
  target is a custom target created in source directory
  "/home/rosuser/catkin_ws/src/rqt_common_plugins/rqt_image_view".
  See documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/groovy/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:280 (include)
  ros_comm/clients/roscpp/CMakeLists.txt:35 (generate_messages)


CMake Error at /home/rosuser/catkin_ws/build/ros_comm/clients/roscpp/cmake/roscpp-genmsg.cmake:147 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "roscpp_generate_messages_py"
  because another target with the same name already exists.  The existing
  target is a custom target created in source directory
  "/home/rosuser/catkin_ws/src/rqt_common_plugins/rqt_image_view".
  See documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/groovy/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:280 (include)
  ros_comm/clients/roscpp/CMakeLists.txt:35 (generate_messages)
```
````

What can be wrong? Thank you!

---

**Update-1**) I see a similar error with different combination, which I've found a workaround for but don't understand yet.

```
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'tf'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(geometry/tf)
-- Boost version: 1.46.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--   signals
-- tf: 1 messages, 1 services
CMake Error at /home/noodlelover/catkinws/build/geometry/tf/cmake/tf-genmsg.cmake:41 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "tf_generate_messages_cpp" because
  another target with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a
  custom target created in source directory
  "/home/noodlelover/catkinws/src/rqt_robot_plugins/rqt_rviz".
  See documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:280 (include)
  geometry/tf/CMakeLists.txt:20 (generate_messages)
:  
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so 
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'tf_conversions'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(geometry/tf_conversions)
-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

Workaround for this is to have the source of `rviz` in workspace. `rviz` is both `build_` and `run_` depended by `rqt_rviz`. I've removed `rqt_rviz` binary.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66320/generate_messages-fails-with-ros_comm/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-07-01

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-08-20**:
Your examples and descriptions of what you have in your workspace are incomplete and do not contain enough information to reproduce the issue. Please state which repos you have in your workspace, which versions and the executed commands including their full output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just had this issue, and I'm not exactly sure what caused it, but I noticed that some of my workspace source folders were on the hydro-devel branch and some on groovy-devel. Make sure you have the correct branches.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.ros.org/users/6661/scpeters/) with karma: 111 on 2014-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have two packages in the same workspace which define the target `roscpp_generate_messages_cpp`.  You probably have a copy of roscpp with a different name in the same workspace.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-07-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if this will be helpful to you or not, but I was getting a very similar error (add_custom_target cannot create target...) with another package, and it turned out that the CMakeLists and package.xml dependencies were specified incorrectly (in this case, you'd want to check the dependencies of rqt_commmon_plugins).

It was really confusing because the error message implied that the package (i.e. rqt_common_plugins) was trying to explicitly build the same target (roscpp_generate_messages_cpp), but in fact it was just an artifact from poorly-defined dependencies. Go figure.

EDIT: Here's the commit that fixed the problem in my package: https://github.com/danepowell/omni_description/commit/b3a738afd01cb58c6d4ab33c1ff7dd5f3aa3c9b0

---

Originally posted by [danep](https://answers.ros.org/users/2877/danep/) with karma: 197 on 2013-08-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-08-20**:
@danep I'm still struggling with this. Can you post what error message you saw in your case if it's available?

**Comment by [danep](https://answers.ros.org/users/2877/danep/) on 2013-08-21**:
Sorry, I don't have the text of the error message. But omni_description has very few dependencies so you could easily download it and build the pre- and post-commit versions to see the error message and resolution for yourself.